# how to make the game replay after the user losse?

Tags: python

```
def your_advntur() :
afdfdf="ff"

start = input("do you want to play ?\n")
a = "-deep voice:"
while start != "yes" :
    if start == "no":
        quit()
    else:
        start = input("pleas answer with yes or no:\n")

name = input(a+" hello adventurer tell me your name.\n-adventurer: my name is ")
path1 = input(a + name+" you found your self in jungle facing a lake without any memory this 
is your story"
         "\nyou can \"cross it\" or \"walk around it\" or \"head back\" what do you want to do 
?\n-"+name+":")
if path1 == "cross the lake" :
    print("brave adventurer which face his problems directly \n"
          "i like it but infurtchn you have been eaten by an aligator\n GAME OVER")
    your_advntur()
    while True:
        response = input("wanna play again?")
        if response == "yes":
            your_advntur()
        else:
            break
```

t tried this but it didnt work i want the game to restart after the user typing yes and close after no and reask the if you want to replay q if the user typed anthor thing

Comment: you place it inside a while True loop (infinite loop aka game loop). To exit out of that loop, have a condition inside to break out of that loop e.g. player says quit.

Comment: i think thats what i did